# How do I use this copy code

Tags: android, eclipse, copy, sd-card

I found this code which appears to be what I need in that it will copy byte for byte a file to the SDCard.

But how do I use it?  say I have a text file called mytext.txt  where do I put it in my application?  and how would I reference it?  I am using Eclipse

```
 public static final void copyfile(String srFile, String dtFile){
        try{
            File f1 = new File(srFile);
            File f2 = new File(dtFile);
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("File copied to " + f2.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a FileUtilities class or somesuch. Have you looked at the examples here?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/FileCopyinJava.htm

You don't want to blindly execute this code. It looks like it's meant for a java console app.  System Printlines do not go anywhere that the user would see in an android application. I do not know what System.exit() does in an Android application, but you don't want to do this either. Depending on your application, you may want to add a toast notification that a copy fails. You want to at least log this.

Depending on the size of files you are copying, you may want to do this in a background thread as to not clog up your UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as another method of your own Activity if your code is small, or you can create a utility class, let's suppose

```
class MyUtilities {
    public static final void copyfile(String srFile, String dtFile) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
        File f1 = new File(srFile);
        File f2 = new File(dtFile);
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        Log.d("MyUtilities", "File copied to " + f2.getAbsolutePath());
   }
}
```

and you will use it as:

```
TextEdit text1 = findViewById(R.id.text1);
TextEdit text2 = findViewById(R.id.text2);

String file1 = text1.getText();
String file2 = text2.getText();

if (text1 != null and text2 != null) {
  try{
    MyUtilities.copyfile (file1, file2);
  } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
      Log.e("MyUtilities", ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.");
  } catch(IOException e){
      Log.e("MyUtilities", e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

I added logs instead of the System.out and changed the Exception mechanism to better match android needs.

Comment: Thank you for helping, if you don't mind I might need a little hand holding...

I have added a class MyUtilities in which is your top set of code and the bottom set of code I have put into my activity, it doesn't seem to know what textedit is and when you reference r.id.text1 and text 2 - what are they?

Where would I put mytext.txt and how would I let the application know this is the file I want copied - sorry I'm such a noob

Comment: @MrCloister text1 and tex2 are example names for `TextEdit` widgets defined in an xml file. I would suggest you to read the Android Dev Guide, specially the UI part: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html and the resources: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Comment: Sorry I was being dense - you have put them there so a user can specify a source and destination path.  I am going to be copying a good number of files automatically, I'll see how I go with this and let you know if I have any success.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first glance that appears to be a sound method, except that you'd want to replace the System.out print statements with an android Log method... but besides that you could copy/paste that and include that method in a class.

To use it, however... you should have a look at the External Storage documentation.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

You're going to need to use Android methods to get correct sdcard directories, etc...